# Dynamic button title inside a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, button

I try to display a tableView with a button on each cell. The title of each button is a variable (an ID) in order to keep this value.

```
NSString *valuebutton = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"idparse"]];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y + 12, 300,35);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
[button setTitle:valuebutton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    return cell;
```

When I try to scroll the tableview on the device the value of the button change and I can see it be modified in live.

Did you see this issue before ?

Thanks for your help !

Alex.

Comment: you should put here the cellForRow method

Comment: Show how you use contactInfoDict object

Comment: what is this [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"idparse"] and nsslog this?and update the question

Comment: I tried that and it works perfectly :
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Thanks Guys ! I love you lol

Comment: May be its a problem of cell reusability, so update your question with cellForRowAtIndexPath() method code.

Comment: To be more specific I replaced the cell definition from :

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

TO : 

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 

following the Bodgan Somlea suggestion and it works fine !

Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it is difficult to debug. However, if you are using dynamic cells then any off screen cells are candidates for being recycled. If you use static cells, then any off screen cells are retained (not recycled). It is possible that off screen cells are being reused (assuming you are using dynamic cells) producing the behavior you described. If you are having issues with your cellForRowAtIndexPath method then that could be the issue too. Please share that code.

Also, looking at your initial code, you might want consider a dynamic prototype cell that includes the button in IB. Then all you need to do is reference the cell within cellForRowAtIndexPath, grab the button of the cell and set its title via the cell indexPath (i.e. cell 0 gets title 0, cell 1 gets title 1, etc.) -- would save you a bit of code.